# Select from JSON with certain conditions

Tags: php, json

If I had the JSON below, how would I get the value of `Name` and `Age` when `ID == 6`?

```
[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"6", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]
```

I have attempted to do this so far but I get the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 3

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"6", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$json2 = json_decode($json);
if($json2->ID == '6') {
   echo $json2->Name;
   echo $json2->Age;
}
```

Comment: The only thing you're missing is a foreach loop, to loop over all objects you have before you try to access the name and age from each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a simple loop:

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"6", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array as $person){
   if($person->ID == '6') {
       echo $person->Name;
       echo $person->Age;
   }
}
```

If you have to access more than one person in the array, it might make sense to create a new array indexed on the id:

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"6", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
$indexPeopleArray=[];
foreach($array as $person){
   $indexPeopleArray[$person->ID]=$person;
}
```

Then you can access each person simply:

```
echo $indexPeopleArray[6]->name; //jim
echo $indexPeopleArray[53]->name; //bob
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using

```
if($json2[0]->ID == '6') {
   echo $json2[0]->Name;
   echo $json2[0]->Age;
}
```

//because in json `[` indicates the array. so when you decode it from using `json_decode` the array created like.

```
array[0][Name]
array[0][Age]
array[0][Age]

array[1][Name]
array[1][Age]
array[1][Age]
```

The answer of @steve is also the right.